# Assembly TASM issues

Tags: assembly, tasm

1)
So, I have this asm code in a .asm file, basically its doing something like

```
BEGIN


X:=2;  
Y:=2+X;
Z:=Y;

IF( Z > X ) THEN  
WRITELN("VALOR DE Z"); 
WRITELN( Z ); 
ELSE 
WRITELN("VALOR DE X"); 
WRITELN( X ); 
END; 

END programa1.
```

ASM here:

```
   ;/StartHeader
INCLUDE macrose.mac
DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
STACK 100h
.DATA
            BUFFER      DB 8 DUP('$')  ;23h
            BUFFERTEMP  DB 8 DUP('$')  ;23h
            BLANCO  DB '#'
            BLANCOS DB '$'
            MENOS   DB '-$'
            COUNT   DW 0
            NEGATIVO    DB 0
            ARREGLO DW 0
            ARREGLO1    DW 0
            ARREGLO2    DW 0
            LISTAPAR    LABEL BYTE
            LONGMAX DB 254
            TOTCAR  DB ?
            INTRODUCIDOS    DB 254 DUP ('$')
                        MULT10  DW 1
                        NUM DW ?
                        X  dw ?
                        Y  dw ?
                        Z  dw ?
            T1 dw ?
            T2 dw ?
                        cadena1 db "VALOR DE Z",'$'
                        cadena2 db "VALOR DE X",'$'
.CODE
.386
BEGIN:
            MOV     AX, @DATA
            MOV     DS, AX
CALL  COMPI
            MOV AX, 4C00H
            INT 21H
COMPI  PROC
    I_ASIGNAR           2, X
    SUMAR               X, 2, T1
    I_ASIGNAR           T1, Y
    I_ASIGNAR           Y, Z
    I_MAYOR MACRO       X, Z, T2
        JF                  T2, P1
    WRITE               cadena1
    ADD                 Z, 30H
    WRITE               Z
        JMP                 Q1
P1: 
    WRITE               cadena2
    ADD                 X, 30H
    WRITE               X
Q1: 
        ret
COMPI  ENDP
END BEGIN
```

And when im trying to run it in cmd dosbox, (cmd in win 7 wont work) with tasm  file.asm im having these errors

*Warning* codigo.asm() Open procedure: COMPI

**Fatal** codigo.asm(55) Unexpected end of file encountered

I dont know why because im pretty sure im closing the procedure and the begin, alse the last line in my file is the 54 and i dont know why is telling me the issue is in line 55.

These macros im using:

```
JF  MACRO VALOR1,DESTINO
    MOV AX,VALOR1
    CMP AX,1                   
    JNE  DESTINO

    ENDM

WRITE   MACRO MESSAGE
        PUSH AX ;EXTRA
        MOV AH, 09H
        LEA DX, MESSAGE
        INT 21H
        POP AX  ;EXTRA
    ENDM

I_ASIGNAR MACRO OPERANDO2, OPERANDO1
        PUSH AX
        MOV AX, OPERANDO2
        MOV OPERANDO1, AX
        POP AX
    ENDM

SUMAR   MACRO OPERANDO2, OPERANDO1, RESULTADO
        PUSH AX
                MOV AX, OPERANDO1
        ADD AX, OPERANDO2
        MOV RESULTADO, AX
        POP AX
    ENDM

I_MAYOR MACRO OPERANDO2, OPERANDO1, RESULTADO
    LOCAL LABEL1
    LOCAL SALIR
        PUSH AX
        MOV AX, OPERANDO1
        CMP AX, OPERANDO2
        JLE LABEL1
        MOV RESULTADO, 1
        JMP SALIR
    LABEL1:
        MOV RESULTADO, 0
    SALIR:
        POP AX
    ENDM
```

2) I have also this code in asm, basically its just doing something like:

```
BEGIN


X:=2;  
Y:=2+X;
Z:=Y;

WRITELN("VALOR DE Z"); 
WRITELN( Z ); 


END programa1.
```

Asm here:

```
;/StartHeader
INCLUDE macrose.mac
DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
STACK 100h
.DATA
            BUFFER      DB 8 DUP('$')  ;23h
            BUFFERTEMP  DB 8 DUP('$')  ;23h
            BLANCO  DB '#'
            BLANCOS DB '$'
            MENOS   DB '-$'
            COUNT   DW 0
            NEGATIVO    DB 0
            ARREGLO DW 0
            ARREGLO1    DW 0
            ARREGLO2    DW 0
            LISTAPAR    LABEL BYTE
            LONGMAX DB 254
            TOTCAR  DB ?
            INTRODUCIDOS    DB 254 DUP ('$')
                        MULT10  DW 1
                        NUM DW ?
                        X  dw ?
                        Y  dw ?
                        Z  dw ?
            T1 dw ?
                        cadena1 db "VALOR DE Z",'$'
.CODE
.386
BEGIN:
            MOV     AX, @DATA
            MOV     DS, AX
CALL  COMPI
            MOV AX, 4C00H
            INT 21H
COMPI  PROC
    I_ASIGNAR           2, X
    SUMAR               X, 2, T1
    I_ASIGNAR           T1, Y
    I_ASIGNAR           Y, Z
    WRITE               cadena1
    ADD                 Z, 30H
    WRITE               Z
        ret
COMPI  ENDP
END BEGIN
```

But im having another issue (im not having the open procedure error though, why?) that im printing: VALOR DE Z1 VALOR DE Z

-Why im printing "VALOR DE Z" twice?
-1 its the answer though, it should print just VALOR DE Z and 1 not twice.
-Im using the same macros I posted up, and also running in Dosbox 0.74

Any ideas? Thanks btw.

P.D. Im in a dell inspiron 64bit n5150 intel core i7 2670Qm 2.20Ghz  6gb ram
Why code format is not working on issue2?

Comment: I've tried fixing the code formatting in that last code blob but I can't seem to get it to stick.

Comment: My suggestion is to remove question 2, leaving just question 1. Then ask a separate SO question for question 2.

Comment: I think the issue with your question #1 is that you have this line `I_MAYOR MACRO X, Z, T2` in the `COMPI` procedure . The word `MACRO` isn't suppose to be there. I think you meant `I_MAYOR  X, Z, T2` .I think that is causing TASM to become confused since it thinks you are starting a new macro.

Comment: Thats right! Thank you very much! I will then ask a new question for issue 2. Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing it was likely a copy and paste error (typographical) while you were coding. If that is the case I'll vote to close question #1 because it was really just a typo.

Comment: As for question #2, you can't use in 21h/ah=09h to print out integer values directly. You have to convert an integer to a string and then call int 21h/ah=09h on the string buffer with the converted value. It printed out the  data starting at the location of variable _Z_. The funny characters you probably had displayed on the console were the Ascii values for the word  in _Z_ then it printed _T1_ (while looking for $) It then continued until it found a terminating $ which happened to be at the end of the _cadena1_ string Once it found the $ it stopped.So it would appear _cadena1_ printed twice.

Comment: Many thanks! one last question, how can I convert the integer to string using stringbuffer? Appreciate the help.

Comment: The normal algorithm is to take the integer value and divide it by 10. The remainder can be added to ASCII '0' to convert the digit to a printable character and store it in a string buffer. You keep dividing by 10 until the dividend is 0. You have to concern yourself with reversing the digits since they will be processed in reverse order. You can find examples of this online if you look.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that MASM requires `COMPI ENDP` but TASM wants only `ENDP`.  Additionally, you have the word `MACRO` in one of your statements:

```
COMPI  PROC
    I_ASIGNAR           2, X
    SUMAR               X, 2, T1
    I_ASIGNAR           T1, Y
    I_ASIGNAR           Y, Z
    I_MAYOR MACRO       X, Z, T2   ; <<<---  Remove "MACRO"
        JF                  T2, P1
    WRITE               cadena1
    ADD                 Z, 30H
    WRITE               Z
        JMP                 Q1
P1: 
    WRITE               cadena2
    ADD                 X, 30H
    WRITE               X
Q1: 
        ret
COMPI ENDP
```

This should resolve your issue in question #1.